# Android News App - External Image and Text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am building a simple news app which shows news from a couple of websites in order. I am building a simple activity to show an image from the news and the title.

From a web app perspective, I need to send a request to server which results a json of the form `{"image": http://example.com/image, "title": "News Title"}` and I need to show this on the page.

How can we do this while making an android app. I am not able to figure out this part of making the app. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand you read these topics:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

As well as the links provided in these pages. Happy learning ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
         Map<String, Object> jsonParamsob = new ArrayMap<>();
         //put something inside the map, could be null
            jsonParamsob.put("phone", "+91"+phoneNumber);
            jsonParamsob.put("otp", ""+otp);
            jsonParamsob.put("deviceType", "android");
            jsonParamsob.put("deviceToken", ""+android_id);
            jsonParamsob.put("appType", "admin");

            /*"phone": "9050292547",
        "otp": "1234",
        "deviceType" : "android",
        "deviceToken": "nxksnnk423lncmklnlkcdss",
        "appType": "admin"*/

            RequestBody bodyRq =  ResponseBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"),(new JSONObject(jsonParamsob)).toString());
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.